# NSUndoManager is undoing all changes done during a mouseDrag with single Undo

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsundomanager

I have an NSView object that takes in mouseDragged events that changes the position of an object drawn in its respective view. In my NSViewController class, it then retrieves that new position and assigns that new value to my model data-object. In other words, *each time* a mouseDragged event is invoked, the ViewController updates the new position. So, in that same scope, the ViewController registers an undo event via NSUndoManager to allow the user perform an Undo action.

The issue arises when multiple position-update-actions are registered into the undo manager. When the user performs an Undo action, instead of only the most recent action getting popped from the undo stack, the rest of the actions also get undone.

For reference, here is my code:

```
// MyViewController.m
- (void)translateObject:(double)dx
          withYPosition:(double)dy
{
    NSMutableDictionary* transformData = [self.transformData transform];

    double t_x = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_x"] doubleValue];
    double t_y = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_y"] doubleValue];

    t_x -= x;
    t_y -= y;

    [self translateShape:@[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t_x],[NSNumberNumberWithDouble:t_y]]];
}

- (void)translateShape:(NSArray*)val
{
    NSMutableDictionary* transformData = [self.transformData transform];

    double old_t_x = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_x"] doubleValue];
    double old_t_y = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_y"] doubleValue];
    double t_x = [[val objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    double t_y = [[val objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

    [transformData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t_x] forKey:@"translate_x"];
    [transformData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t_y] forKey:@"translate_y"];
    [self.transformData setTransform:transformData];
    [self.glView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

    [[self undoManager] registerUndoWithTarget:self
                                  selector:@selector(translateShape:)
                                    object:@[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:old_t_x],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithDouble:old_t_y]]];

    [[self undoManager] setActionName:@"Shape Drag Move"];  
}

/* * * I have also done this:

- (void)translateShape:(NSArray*)val
{
    NSMutableDictionary* transformData = [self.transformData transform];

    double old_t_x = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_x"] doubleValue];
    double old_t_y = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_y"] doubleValue];
    double t_x = [[val objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    double t_y = [[val objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

    [transformData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t_x] forKey:@"translate_x"];
    [transformData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t_y] forKey:@"translate_y"];
    [self.transformData setTransform:transformData];
    [self.glView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

    [[self undoManager] registerUndoWithTarget:self
                                  selector:@selector(unTranslateShape:)
                                    object:@[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:old_t_x],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithDouble:old_t_y]]];

    [[self undoManager] setActionName:@"Shape Drag Move"];  
}

- (void)unTranslateShape:(NSArray*)val
{
    NSMutableDictionary* transformData = [self.transformData transform];

    double old_t_x = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_x"] doubleValue];
    double old_t_y = [[transformData objectForKey:@"translate_y"] doubleValue];
    double t_x = [[val objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    double t_y = [[val objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

    [transformData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t_x] forKey:@"translate_x"];
    [transformData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t_y] forKey:@"translate_y"];
    [self.transformData setTransform:transformData];
    [self.glView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

    [[self undoManager] registerUndoWithTarget:self
                                  selector:@selector(translateShape:)
                                    object:@[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:old_t_x],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithDouble:old_t_y]]];

    [[self undoManager] setActionName:@"Shape Redo Drag Move"]; 
}

* * */
```

Below is a poorly made diagram of what I expected the undo to happen, versus what I'm actually observing:

[image]

Can anyone shed light on this? Thank you.

Comment: Are the mouseDragged events just events or is a dragging session involved? Is "multiple position-update-actions" one drag or multiple drags?

Comment: Just a guess: try adding the `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` to the undo manager's `runLoopModes` property.

Comment: @Willeke: The position/translation value is updated on one drag, I guess it just depends on how long/far the user has dragged their mouse.

Comment: @JamesBucanek: It did not work. But perhaps I should take that as a hint and dig deeper on how Cocoa's NSUndoManager groups undo actions during a runLoop pass. Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't find the documents anymore (I *hate* it that Apple API docs no longer link to the relevant developer guides), but if memory serves me, an undo group is created and closed on each iteration through the run loop. If you're circumventing the run loop somehow, you may need to close each group yourself.

Comment: Documentation: [Undo Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/UndoArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000010i)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to James Bucanek's hint about setting NSUndoManager's runLoopModes, I was able to figure out why NSUndoManager was undoing all of my registered undos during a mouseDown, mouseDragged, and mouseUp events. Turns out in my case, the NSUndoManager groups all undos registered by event *(which I suppose that also means any undo actions registered in a mouseDragged event)*. For simply registering undos in your NSView subclass, the following should work:

```
/** Simple case: Everything handled by NSView subclass **/

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    // Set your undo manager's groupsByEvent property to NO here
}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
{
    // Tell your undo manager to begin grouping
    // Register undo and redo actions here
    // Tell your undo manager to end grouping
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
    // Set your undo manager's groupsByEvent property to YES here
}
```

Since I'm using a protocol to set my model's attributes in my view controller, I simply implemented another method in that said protocol that is called during my NSView's mouseDown/mouseUp events to subsequently setGroupsByEvent to NO and YES. If anyone knows a much better implementation/solution to this issue, feel free to correct me. Hope this helps!